# ¿Cómo cambiar los elementos uno a uno con JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

buenos días y gracias de antemano.
Lo que quiero es **cambiar el color del primer circulo, pero que no me deje cambiar ninguno más hasta que este no vuelva a la normalidad.

Y luego ir cambiando de la misma forma el resto de circulos.**
Tengo el siguiente html:

```
<body>
    <div id="arriba" class="arriba"></div>
    <div id="principal" class="principal">
      <div>
        <span id="circulo" class="circulo">1</span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span id="circulo1" class="circulo">2</span>
        <span id="circulo2" class="circulo">3</span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span id="circulo3" class="circulo">4</span>
        <span id="circulo4" class="circulo">5</span>
        <span id="circulo5" class="circulo">6</span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span id="circulo6" class="circulo">7</span>
        <span id="circulo7" class="circulo">8</span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span id="circulo8" class="circulo">9</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="abajo" class="abajo"></div>
  </body>
```

Mi archivo css es el siguiente:

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
html,
body {

    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
#circulo {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #5cb85c;
}
```

Y repito el proceso para cada id (circulo - circulo8)
La parte de JS que tengo hasta ahora es la siguiente:

```
function cambiarColor(i) {
  //alert("La celda tiene id: "+ i.target.id);
  alert("Esta entrando a cambiar color");
  
  
}

let circulos = document.getElementsByClassName("circulo");

for (let i = 0; i < circulos.length; i++) {
  circulos[i].addEventListener("click", cambiarColor(i));
  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`introducir el código aquí`Espero te funcione... vas cambiando el selecionado... puedes quitar a todos el background y poner solo al activo.

```js
let divs = document.getElementsByClassName("circulo");
const cambiarColor = (e) => {
    let objetivo = e.target.classList
    for (let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        if(divs[i].classList.contains('agregarcolor')){
            objetivo.remove('agregarcolor')
        }else{
            divs[i].classList.add('agregarcolor')
        }
    }
}

for (let i=0; i< divs.length; i++) {
    divs[i].addEventListener("click" ,cambiarColor)    
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
html,
body {

    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}


.circulo{
    font-size: 30px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}



.agregarcolor{
    background-color: #5cb85c;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="arriba" class="arriba"></div>
    <div id="principal" class="principal">
      <div>
        <span id="circulo" class="circulo agregarcolor">1</span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span id="circulo1" class="circulo agregarcolor">2</span>
        <span id="circulo2" class="circulo agregarcolor">3</span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span id="circulo3" class="circulo agregarcolor">4</span>
        <span id="circulo4" class="circulo agregarcolor">5</span>
        <span id="circulo5" class="circulo agregarcolor">6</span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span id="circulo6" class="circulo agregarcolor">7</span>
        <span id="circulo7" class="circulo agregarcolor">8</span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span id="circulo8" class="circulo agregarcolor">9</span>
        <span id="circulo8" class="circulo agregarcolor">10</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="abajo" class="abajo"></div>
  </body>
  <script src="./javascript/script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes dos problemas bastante sencillos:

1. Estás usando el selector equivocado en css. `#` se utiliza para ids no para clases, para las clases se usa un punto `.class`, En tu CSS debería decir `.circulo`.
2. `addEventListener` recibe una **referencia a la función**, no su resultado, por tanto retira los paréntesis de `cambiarColor(i)`. Debería quedar `circulos[i].addEventListener("click", cambiarColor)`

Con estos cambios puedes obtener el resultado deseado.

```js
var elementoSeleccionado;
function cambiarColor(i) {
  if(elementoSeleccionado)
     elementoSeleccionado.style.backgroundColor = "#5cb85c"
  
  i.target.style.backgroundColor =  "red"
  elementoSeleccionado = i.target
}

let circulos = document.getElementsByClassName("circulo");
for (let i = 0; i < circulos.length; i++) {
  circulos[i].addEventListener("click", cambiarColor);
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
html,
body {

    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.circulo {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #5cb85c;

    
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="arriba" class="arriba"></div>
    <div id="principal" class="principal">
      <div>
        <span id="circulo" class="circulo">1</span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span id="circulo1" class="circulo">2</span>
        <span id="circulo2" class="circulo">3</span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span id="circulo3" class="circulo">4</span>
        <span id="circulo4" class="circulo">5</span>
        <span id="circulo5" class="circulo">6</span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span id="circulo6" class="circulo">7</span>
        <span id="circulo7" class="circulo">8</span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span id="circulo8" class="circulo">9</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="abajo" class="abajo"></div>
  </body>
```